# Problem on some Android devices (Empty view)

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I have an app on google play and since the latest release I've gotten two reviews about the content of the app not showing up. I've googled a whole bunch but can't seem to find anyone with the same problem. Can somebody help me?

If you look in the first picture, that's how the app is supposed to look like
https://i.stack.imgur.com/pfb22.jpg

If you now look in the same gif which one of my users sent, you can see that the app is completely blank, except for the tabbar
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qqomf.jpg

I am calling setContentView in onCreate so that can't be it I guess

```
 override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.main_activity)
```

}

Any clues?

Comment: Can you provide more code which is responsible for setting up the actual content of the activity and the tab bar?

Comment: As you can see in the gif, the call to `setContentView(...)` succeeds because the tab bar is shown. The bug must be somewhere down the line after that call.

Comment: This is the whole onCreate function
https://pastebin.com/X0hHpXsj

What's confusing to me is that it only seem to happen on a fraction of all devices. One OnePlus 5 and one Samsung Galaxy Note 10